# Sharing angular environment as npm package across projects

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, security, npm

I am working on a project that I am required to create **two separate angular** projects but I want them to **share the same environment object** which contains my firebase configuration. It is a **good idea to create a custom npm package** say called environments and save my environment objects there. This is how the index.ts of my custom package looks like.

```
//environments/index.ts    
//production environment
    export const environment_prod = {
      production: true,
      firebase: {
        apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        databaseURL: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        projectId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      }
    };


    //development environment
    export const environment_dev = {
      production: false,
      firebase: {
        apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        databaseURL: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        projectId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      }
    };
```

In the environments of each project, I import the configuration from the shared npm package? This is how my production environment now looks like

```
import { environment_prod } from 'environments';

export const environment = environment_prod;
```

In my development environment, I have this:

```
//loading  environment_dev from my custom npm package
import { environment_dev } from 'environments';

export const environment = environment_dev;
```

I wish to know if this has any security implications and if I should change my approach. I have also add my custom npm package folder to my .gitignore file so that it isn't pushed to my git repo. Thanks for taking the time to read through my long and boring essay

Comment: A heads up. The next version of the angular-cli will make use of TypeScript 3 which supports [project references](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html). It makes it easier to share such files across projects.

Comment: Personally, I do not think it is a good idea to package the `Firebase` config object into an `npm` package. `Firebase` config objects are always specific to individual project needs and if required to be shared across within the team, then the config object `ts` source could be tracked. But, I'm not in favor of packaging the `Firebase` config object into an npm package.